# Htacess redirect path in depth

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect:

```
https://latestmodapks.com/pt/download-de-dados-gta-4-apk-obb-para-android-e-ios/anythinghere
```

OR

```
https://latestmodapks.com/pt/download-de-dados-gta-4-apk-obb-para-android-e-ios/anythinghere/
```

to

```
https://latestmodapks.com/pt/download-de-dados-gta-4-apk-obb-para-android-e-ios/download
```

Replace (anythinghere or anythinghere/ with download)

After trying a bit, I think this code should work:

```
RewriteRule https://latestmodapks.com/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*) https://latestmodapks.com/$1/$2/download [R=301,NC,L]
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all. What am I missing here?
Using openlitespeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't match scheme, port or hostname etc in `RewriteRule`.

Use your rule like this:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(pt/.*/)[^/]+/?$ /$1/download [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

**Breakup:**

- `(.*/)` will match any path starting with `pt/` then longest possible match ending with `/` in capture group #1.
- `[^/]+` will match 1+ of any char that is not `/` (last path component)
- Target is `/$1/download` that replaces only last path component with `download`

Comment: Thank you for your time. But this scheme is also matching URL like https://latestmodapks.com/fmwhatsapp-apk-download/werrew/ which I don't want.

Comment: instead of anythinghere, there can be any string here. for example: https://latestmodapks.com/pt/download-de-dados-gta-4-apk-obb-para-android-e-ios/new-redirect should also goto my desired url which is 
https://latestmodapks.com/pt/download-de-dados-gta-4-apk-obb-para-android-e-ios/download